# How to pass a directory name with spaces into a variable in unix

Tags: variables, unix, directory

I have a directory //10.150.33.150/Data/"Task Logs 150"/.

When I'm passing the entire string to a variable , its successful.

But when I'm trying to call the variable , it's giving error.

PFB error screenshot :

```
abhisek.samanta@COMCSTREFDB01 /cygdrive/c/Managed_Services/Scripts/Incomplete_DL/Script
$ a=//10.150.33.150/Data/"Task Logs 150"/

abhisek.samanta@COMCSTREFDB01 /cygdrive/c/Managed_Services/Scripts/Incomplete_DL/Script
$ cd $a
-sh: cd: //10.150.33.150/Data/Task: No such file or directory
```

Pl help .

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

use single apex on the whole parameter:

```
a='//10.150.33.150/Data/Task Logs 150/'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to quote the variable when you use it:

```
cd "$a"
```